# What sort of algorithm/communication model/data structure do collaborative real time editors use?

Tags: data-structures, efficiency

I am researching collaborative editing systems for some work, but so far my search is turning up blank.

Collaborative real-time editing systems almost all have features like:

- Many users can edit the document at the same time
- All changes are dated and saved in a linear revision history
- Edits are visible in semi-real time
- Who-wrote-what is tracked for all content

I cannot think of a data- and procedure model to encompass all of these without huge inefficiencies, for example:

- Take user input as a few typestrokes at a time, thus enabling real-time visibility but with horrible server loads.
- Take user input as element changes, thus disabling real-time visibility and complicating many-user-editing of one paragraph.
- Edit a XML Document Model Object in place responding to inputs, but making it difficult to version/revision track.
- Edit linear text stored in an appropriate editing structure responding to inputs, making it difficult to verify that correct markup is being generated.
- Store revision history accumulating, requiring computational resources but easing on space.
- Store revision history whole, requiring space but easing on computation.

Am I off track? Does there exist good solutions to these problems? What, if any, is the relevant litterature?

Comment: Are you interested in developing such a system, or do you ask if a system that provides this functionality is known?

Comment: Have you looked into existing collarborative editors?

Comment: @A.Schulz I am interested in ultimately developing such a system tailored to a specific purpose, but right now is Research only.

Comment: @Raphael I am investigating Etherpad, but if I am not mistaken, there isn't a lot of open-source systems of this kind.

Comment: I have used [Gobby](https://gobby.0x539.de/trac/) myself, which is open source. There [seem to be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_real-time_editor#Real-time_collaborative_text_editing_software) about handful of open-source collaborative editors, including Etherpad.

Answer (score 4):

The usual approach is operational transformation. The [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation) seems to be pretty good. Here are some other references:

- [Understanding and Applying Operational Transformation](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/understanding-and-applying-operational-transformation)
- [Operational Transformation: An Introduction](http://fitzgeraldnick.com/weblog/41/)
- [OT FAQ](http://cooffice.ntu.edu.sg/otfaq/)
- [ShareJS](http://sharejs.org/) - javascript library implementing OT

Here's a paper on a different approach: [Real time group editors without operational transformation](http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/07/12/40/PDF/RR-5580.pdf). (Note: I haven't actually read it, so can't speak to how good it is)

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the magical keyword I lacked.